# I want to read a delimited or csv file and save the corresponding values in postgres DB

Tags: java, postgresql, csv

I need to write a code to read the values from a csv or delimited text file and save the corresponding values in a DB table.I am able to do this for csv files easily using the CSVReader utility.
But I am not able to decide how to approach the delimited case.
This is a part of my sample delimited file:

counterparty_id|counterparty_name|counterparty_type|counterparty_company_number

1|Jefferies||

2|ABNAMRO|ABNAMRO|234567

3|Wells Fargo|Wells Fargo|345678

This is the corresponding part of the table in postgres DB,public schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.CARDS_COUNTERPARTY (
counterparty_id     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
counterparty_name   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
counterparty_type   VARCHAR(255)          ,
counterparty_company_number VARCHAR(255)  ,
CONSTRAINT PK_CARDS_COUNTERPARTY PRIMARY KEY (counterparty_id)
```

) ;

My JAVA code should be able to read the values from the file and save or update in the DB table.Below is a snippet from the code that I used for the CSV file:

```
..
CsvReader counterparties = new CsvReader(filename);
        counterparties.readHeaders();
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres",  "root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String query;
        while(counterparties.readRecord())
        {
            String counterpartyId = counterparties.get("counterparty_id");
            String counterpartyName = counterparties.get("counterparty_name");
            String counterpartyType=counterparties.get("counterparty_type");
            String counterpartyCompanyNumber =   counterparties.get("counterparty_company_number");
..               
            query = "insert into public.cards_counterparty values (";
            query = (new  StringBuilder()).append(query).append(counterpartyId).append(", '").toString();
            query = (new StringBuilder()).append(query).append(counterpartyName).append("', '").toString();
            query = (new StringBuilder()).append(query).append(counterpartyType).append("', '").toString();
            query = (new StringBuilder()).append(query).append(counterpartyCompanyNumber).append("', '").toString();
..                
            out.println((new StringBuilder()).append("Query :    ").append(query).toString());
            st.executeUpdate(query);
        }

        out.println("Data inserted...");
        counterparties.close();
..
```

Can someone please tell me how I can read and update the values from the delimited file also in a generic way like the above.I do not want the values to be read to be dependent on the order of the headers in the file.

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what the problem is. Looking at the code above, it appears that you are reading the individual fields from the CVS correctly and then building your statement.

Comment: @Lex Webb: I want to do the same thing i.e., read individual fields from a delimited text file(other than csv) and then build my statement.

Comment: Right, i see what you mean now. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use openCSV much easier than faffing about with a BufferedReader!

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @DavidBillingsThis is exactly what I was looking for.I was not aware that CsvReader can be used for delimiters other than comma too.Thanks a lot for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `BufferedReader` to read in the file line by line, you can then split each line into a string array using `String.split("|")`. This can then be assigned to any field you wish, or put into your SQL DB.

Comment: @LexWebbThanks for your suggestion.I was trying using BufferedReader and String.split only.But using CsvReader with custom quote characters as suggested by DavidBillings is really easier and straight-forward.

Comment: Yes i believe it would be! I just prefer doing things manually than using third party library sometimes!